# What programs can I safely remove if I root my nexus 7?

Tags: android

Is there a current list of programs/apps that can safely be removed if I root a nexus 7 tablet? I want to get rid of the crapware that is now on the machine but don't know which ones. Thanks

Comment: [There is an app for that](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-remove-bloatware-from-your-rooted-android-device/)

Answer (score 0):

System App Remover will do it for you and recommend what not to remove to preserve functionality.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp